# gnupg 2.1.22 'hangs' when generating a key on macOS

Tags: macos, gnupg

I installed `gnupg` under macOS 10.12.6 via `brew install gnupg` (`gpg --version` correctly works). When I tried to generate a 4096bit RSA key via `gpg2 --full-generate-key`, it hangs at "`We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.`" No `+` appears, although I heavily used the disks for 15min. Is this a bug? This used to work (but my last working version I tried was gpg 1.4.19).

There are various posts addressing Linux (e.g., [CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/471412/gpg-gen-key-hangs-at-gaining-enough-entropy-on-centos-6) or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/214605/gpg-does-not-have-enough-entropy)), but nothing which immediately carries over to macOS.

My ~/.gnupg looks quite differently than under 1.4.19: it contains the empty files `S.gpg-agent`, `S.gpg-agent.browser`, `S.gpg-agent.extra` and `S.gpg-agent.ssh`, a file named `pubring.kbx` and an empty folder named `private-keys-v1.d`. Under 1.4.19, it used to contain the files `gpg.conf`, `pubring.gpg`, `random_seed`, `secring.gpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'hanging' came from the 4096bit. Once I went to the (default) 2048bit, there was no problem. Further issues arose thereafter and were due to the changes from gnupg 1.x.x to 2.x.x. They are explained [here](https://colinxy.github.io/software-installation/2016/09/24/emacs25-easypg-issue.html).